# Can we create kafka time windowed stream from historical data?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have some historical data, each record has their timestamp. I would like to read them and feed them into kafka topic, and use kafka stream to process them in a time windowed manner.

Now the question is, when I create kafka stream time windowed aggregation processor, how can I tell kafka to use timestamp field in the record to create time window, instead of real live time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a custom [`TimestampExtractor`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#streams-developer-guide-timestamp-extractor) that will extract the value from the record itself - there's an example of this in the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#streams-developer-guide-timestamp-extractor), and [here too](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview/JsonTimestampExtractor.java). I also found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nfo/54d5830720e163d2e7e848b6e4baac20) which looks relevant.

Comment: May want to set retention on the window too?